# Manage identical dhcp servers

Tags: networking, dhcp, vlan

I have a weird problem that needs a solution. I have many identical DHCP Servers, configured the same way, same subnet, same range, same everything (are actually some PCs) and i would like to somehow connect them to the same client. I can use other devices in the middle (between the dhcp servers and the client) but i cannot change anything in the dhcp servers (they need to be configured in the same way for a different purpose). I know that this is exactly the opposite of how dhcp works.

Maybe some ideas how to fake/mask the identical ip addresses of the servers with a device in between the client and the servers?

Any idea on how i can handle this?

Comment: Not clear what you're after here. A client is only going to ever have a single address. That may change over time, but at any given instant, one address, and all things being equal, that will be the one from the server that responded first. The client will typically ask if it can continue to use the address it is currently using and if that address is still available the server will agree, so even with multiple servers that address should not change.